How do I use Terraform github_repository_pull_request repeatedly?
I want to keep files in a particular branch of a GitHub repo in sync using Terraform. When they differ from the master branch, I want to use the GitHub provider repository_pull_request resource to issue a PR from my synced branch. The aim here is to allow the owner of the repo to decide whether to fix the drift or not.
However, if I create a PR and then I merge it and then the files in the master branch subsequently drift from the synced branch, I need to recreate the PR but the PR already exists. Even if I give the PR resource a composite id made from the sha contents of the file in master and the contents of the synced file I can still get a failure:
Initially:
// in master/foo.txt:
bar


// in sync/foo.txt:
foo

After PR:
// in master/foo.txt:
foo


// in sync/foo.txt:
foo

Now the master file is re-edited:
// in master/foo.txt:
bar


// in sync/foo.txt:
foo

and lo, the PR cannot be created again because it already exists. I can't add a uuid to the composite id because Terraform doesn't allow that.
How can I have the PR always created if the two files are different?

This sounds like a git flow workflow problem (https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow), which you are trying to solve via terraform, and that is an overkill TBH.
--- Another alternative to address this problem is to use git hook. More to this at https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks
